# How to Pass Value from Angular Controller to a template code in Razor

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I'm doing my very first application in ASP.NET MVC 5 with AngularJS and I'm not very good at it yet. My challenge here is pretty simple;

I have an Enum whose values are stored in the database. So when displaying records from the table on a grid, I want to display the Enum Names and not the value. So I decided to use `@Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), valueFromController)`but I don't know how to pass the value from the controller into the method to display the name. This is what I have

```
                     <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
                        <td>
                            <span>{{item.id}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>@Enum.GetName(typeof(PeriodStatus), {{item.status}})</span>
                        </td>

                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="vm.deleteWorkType(workType)"></span></td>
                    </tr>
```

I know this isn't right. Please can someone point me to the right direction. Many thanks.

Comment: So are you getting the data from an api controller? Can't you do the conversion there and return only the data that you require?

Comment: @Ric Thanks for your response. Actually I'm getting the items from "items" collection in angularJS which explains the `ng-repeat="item in vm.items`. If your idea would work, can you show me a sample of how to do it? Sorry I just started using AngularJS a few weeks ago. Thanks.

Comment: I gathered that, but what I'm asking is how are you getting the data? Do you make an API call?

Comment: @Ric. Yes it's an API call.

Comment: Do you have control of this API?

Comment: @Ric I guess so. It's from a script I created if I really understand what you're saying.

Comment: Is the API written in c#/vb and do you have access to the server side code?

Comment: @Ric This is what makes exposes my ApplicationService class to be called by web API: `DynamicApiControllerBuilder
                .ForAll<IApplicationService>(typeof(MyApplicationModule).Assembly, "app")
                .Build();`